# Google Chrome Version updating

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to install older version of Google Chrome. I am able to install older versions on my machine, but as soon as installation processes are getting completed, it will start updating the latest version automatically. This stops me to do my work.

Can anyone suggest me how to stop this auto updating process in chrome.

Thanks,
Sourabh

Comment: I was able to find how to do within 2 minutes of looking for [it](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates)

Answer (score 0):

in services.msc disable the google update services all of them it varies how many you have installed, without this service it can't update

Comment: This isn't the best way to disable updates.  Easier to use the group policy method.